# SD card image transfer using xbee

Tags: arduino, xbee

I trying to read SD card image from arduino (20KB - JPEG -using SD library) and transfer through Xbee (series 2) Due to limitation on xbee, have to break to 60 bytes and send until the  complete file send. I think, the image  stored in ASCII character.

```
 void setup() {

 Serial.begin(115200);

 if (!SD.begin()) {

Serial.println("begin failed");
return;
       }

 file = SD.open("PIC00.JPG");

 }
   void loop() {
   Serial.flush();

char buf[64];
if(file) {
while (file.position() < file.size())
         { 
   while (file.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) == sizeof(buf))  // read chunk of 64bytes 
         {

        Serial.write(buf); // Send to xbee via serial
         delay(50); 
         }

      }
       file.close();
} }
```

But this method, i can not see complete image  transfer   at Serial Write.  After a while, i came to know the start of image is Y (ascii chracter) and  U (end character). I can see only end start character Y can not see the proper end character.

Please advise...trying hard solve this issue. Big Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The JPEG is actually binary data.  To send it, use the version of `Serial.write()` that includes a length parameter for the number of bytes to send.  Otherwise, it thinks you're trying to send a null-terminated string.

(Declare `bytesread` as a `byte` at the top of your function.)

```
while ((bytesread = file.read(buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
{
    Serial.write(buf, bytesread); // Send to xbee via serial
    delay(50); 
}
```

Also note that the delay might not be sufficient -- you should really be using a serial port with hardware flow control (monitoring `/CTS` from the XBee module) so you know when it's clear to send data to it.

Comment: Did not try this method because the sending  all the data continuously through  serial (xbee). Reduced the delay from 50ms to 5ms. And image size is less than 3KB,So, works  though photo and resolution is not great. Thanks.

Comment: Chandra, if you had hardware flow control, you wouldn't need to use the delay.  With the delay, a slow network connection could result in you overflowing the serial buffers on the XBee.  The delay is a hack/workaround and using flow control is the proper and robust solution.

Comment: I never tried hardware flow control. So, have to bother sender Xbee and receiver Xbee use hardware flow control configured. Right?

Comment: It's not necessary for both sender and receiver to make use of hardware flow control.  Keep in mind that the serial connection between host and XBee only affects communication between those devices -- it doesn't have an impact on other hosts on your network.  You can have XBee modules using different baud rates, with or without flow control.